# How to get a pointer to a string in C using the reference operator?

Tags: c, string, pointers, reference

Is there anyway given a string like, `"my example\n"`, to get a pointer to it? For instance, `&"my example\n"` or `&{"my example\n"}`?

EDIT: I guess asking rudimentary questions is what I get for not sleeping last night. Ah well, thanks for all your help anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already a pointer:

```
char *string = "my string\n";
```

`string` will be a pointer to the literal string.

Comment: It's actually an array (look at what happens if you apply `sizeof` to it) but it decays to a pointer in most contexts.

Comment: @R.. yes I see, but I'm just trying not to complicate it too much. The question was asking how to get a pointer to the literal -- and that's what I tried to show

Answer (score 3):

It already is an address.

Example: `char * addr= "my example\n";`

Here, the variable `addr` holds the address of the string.

Answer (score 1):

To your code, a string constant appears as a pointer; specifically a character pointer char* to the first character in the string.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be more strict: the string literals are of type `const char[]`. However `const char[]` can be implicitly casted into `const char*`. So you can easily obtain the pointer by assigning

```
const char* p = "string";
```

Please note that if your next line would be

```
const char* p1 = "string";
```

--the value of `p1` is not guaranteed to be equal to the value of `p`: different string constants may have different addresses (but don't need to).

Note that `p` will be pointer to the first character rather than to the whole string.

Another caveats is that you shouldn't try to get the `char*` pointer (by casting `const` away), as this will result in undefined behaviour. For example, the compiler may put the string literal into the read-only memory, and the program will simply crash.

Comment: "Implicitly cast" is an oxymoron, and what you're describing is actually stronger than an implicit conversion. In most contexts, an array decays to a pointer regardless of whether you want it to or not.

Comment: Well, the proper explanation is [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html), but I wanted to give some basic idea of what happens "behind the scene".